# Exactly matching the keys of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have a search query in the form of an array like below:

```
$searcharray = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2);
```

The code I have written returns multiple results array all of which have the search array key-value pairs. Some results have some extra key-value pairs as well:

```
$resultsarray1 = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7);
$resultsarray2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
$resultsarray3 = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
$resultsarray4 = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2);
$resultsarray5 = array('red'  => 2, 'blue' => 1);
$resultsarray6 = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'cyan'   => 8);
```

I want to write a function which compares these result arrays to the search array and returns just the arrays which have an exact match of the keys in the search array. That is, for the example above the function should return $resultarray4 and $resultarray5 as matching with the search array. Order of keys is not important.

I have tried various combinations of php intersect array functions but the desired result is not being produced.

Comment: There's one confusion in your question. Do you only require keys to match? or values as well?

Comment: Only keys. Values can be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not know it but you can simply use `==` for array comparison

```
if($array1==$array2)
{
     //same key value pairs
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/iKs9pkBM)**

```
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray1);
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray2);
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray3);
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray4);
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray5);
var_dump($searcharray==$resultsarray6);
```

**Output**

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)      //4
bool(true)      //5
bool(false)
```

**And interestingly**

If you want to be even more strict and require that they should return true even if the order of keys is same then you can simply use `===`

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/axpQUDbB)**

Comment: I love it when something that looks like it might be hard is so damn easy. :) Good answer.

Comment: @TunaMaxx: "returns just the arrays which have an exact match of the keys in the search array". This checks both keys and values.

Comment: @Amadan true. I have added an answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Amadan's comment, this function will compare the the keys only, regardless of key order (but that is configurable with the third argument):

```
function find_indentical_keys($array1 = array(), $array2 = array(), $ignore_key_order = true)
{
    if ($ignore_key_order)
    {
        ksort($array1);
        ksort($array2);
    }

    return array_keys($array1) === array_keys($array2);
}
```

Use it like this (with the $resultsarrays made into a an array to make it easy):

```
$searcharray = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2);

$resultsarray[1] = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7);
$resultsarray[2] = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
$resultsarray[3] = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);
$resultsarray[4] = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2);
$resultsarray[5] = array('red'  => 2, 'blue' => 1);
$resultsarray[6] = array('blue' => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'cyan'   => 8);

foreach ($resultsarray as $key => $array)
{
    echo 'Array #' . $key . ' ';
    echo (find_indentical_keys($searcharray, $array)) ? 'MATCHES' : 'does NOT match';
    echo ' the search array.<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/array_intersect_key). This function compares arrays by their keys and returns the matches...